# Typescript group array by key

Tags: javascript, typescript

How can I type the reduce function parameters.

```
interface IGroupArrayByKey<T> {
    data: T[]
    key: string
}

export const groupArrayByKey = <T>({ data, key }: IGroupArrayByKey<T>): object => {
    return data.reduce((acc: any, item: any) => {
        return { ...acc, [item[key]]: [...(acc[item[key]] || []), item] }
    }, {})
}
```

`groupArrayByKey` function works on the principle that you provide the array as a `date` and `key` which the array should be grouped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of notes:

1. `keyof T` lists all properties of type T and doesn't allow passing arbitrary string that is not a key of the object there. Very useful imho.
2. We cannot guarantee that `item[keyProp]` is a string, but indexer in an object could only be a string or a number. That's why this ugly `as unknown as string`. If you would have used a `Map`, then we wouldn't need the cast.

```
interface IGroupArrayByKey<T> {
    data: T[]
    keyProp: keyof T
}

export const groupArrayByKey = <T>({ data, keyProp }: IGroupArrayByKey<T>) => {
    return data.reduce<{ [key: string]: T[] }>((acc, item) => {
        const key = item[keyProp] as unknown as string;
        return { ...acc, [key]: [...(acc[key] || []), item] }
    }, {})
}
```